# Importing init_db (flask tutorial)

Tags: python, import, flask

I have been through the tutorial on flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/introduction/)

And now I am getting errors, can you help me please? :)

On github it says this in the readme... (https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr/)

```
fire up a python shell and run this:

from flaskr import init_db; init_db()
```

So I open my python shell and type it in... Only problem is that I get an import error saying it cannot find flaskr...

If I try run the flaskr.py file locally I just get this

```
sqlite3.OperationalError OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I am really new to this and python in general so any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the database file?

On line 19 in [flaskr.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/examples/flaskr/flaskr.py), the path to the database is given.

```
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
```

That file needs to exist.

Comment: Within my flaskr folder I have another folder called tmp and I put a blank file called flaskr.db in there... I had/have no idea what to put there... 

Sorry, I am really bad at this.

Comment: This is your absolute path. Which OS are you on? Just do this: create a blank file in the flaskr folder called flaskr.db, just beside the flaskr.py file. And change the line 19 to read `DATABASE = 'flaskr.db'`. That is all. And then run the command.

Comment: I am using windows 7 ultimate. 

I did what you said and it gave me the same import error...

I'm going to sound even more stupid now, but all I do is go to my python27 folder, open up the python.exe and then type it in and run it... I am going to guess I'm doing something wrong? -.-

Comment: You will need a bit of studying to get Python running the way you want. :) Here you go: [Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows). Read it carefully and see how to run a script.

Comment: Use `DATABASE = '.\\tmp\\flaskr.db'` if you are using Windows.